# Calendar.current shows a day before yesterday instead of current time

Tags: swift

Right now it is 04/13/2020 at 2:33 AM and I am testing on an actual device.

I am trying to use [Calendar.current](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/calendar/2293438-current), get the start of the day.

When I ran this code in below

```
extension Date {
    var startOfDay: Date {
      return Calendar.current.startOfDay(for: self)
    }
}
```

I was expecting to see a date of 04/13 but instead, I got the date as:

```
▿ 2020-04-12 07:00:00 +0000
  - timeIntervalSinceReferenceDate : 608367600.0
```

and this value is constant, which led me to think that I have a constant calendar timezone setting and it is not the case.

this is what the `Calendar.current` looks like:

```
gregorian (current)
  - identifier : Foundation.Calendar.Identifier.gregorian
  - kind : "current"
  ▿ locale : Optional<Locale>
    ▿ some : en_US (current)
      - identifier : "en_US"
      - kind : "current"
  ▿ timeZone : America/Los_Angeles (current)
    - identifier : "America/Los_Angeles"
    - kind : "current"
    ▿ abbreviation : Optional<String>
      - some : "PDT"
    - secondsFromGMT : -25200
    - isDaylightSavingTime : true
  - firstWeekday : 1
  - minimumDaysInFirstWeek : 1
```

I was expecting to see the date as the current date based on my timezone. I have no idea why Calendar.current doesn't return my actual timezone ( I didn't modify my calendar timezone)

Thanks for reading

Comment: Did you at any time have a different system setting for the current date time. From the documentation `The returned calendar is formed from the settings for the current user’s chosen system locale overlaid with any custom settings the user has specified in System Preferences. Settings you get from this calendar do not change as System Preferences are changed, so that your operations are consistent`. Did you try using `autoupdatingCurrent`?

Comment: `2020-04-12 07:00:00 UTC` _**is**_ `2020-04-13 00:00:00` _in your time zone_. Nothing's wrong.

Answer (score 0):

**Try below code:**

```
extension Date {
func localDate() -> Date {
    let currentDate = Date()
    let timeZoneOffset = Double(TimeZone.current.secondsFromGMT(for: currentDate))
    guard let localDate = Calendar.current.date(byAdding: .second, value: Int(timeZoneOffset), to: currentDate) else {return Date()}

    return localDate
}}
```

**OR Try this one:**

```
extension Date {
var startOfDay: Date {
    let dateFormatter = DateFormatter()
    dateFormatter.dateFormat = "MM-dd-yyyy HH:mm"
    guard let date = dateFormatter.date(from: Date().description(with: .current)) else { return Date() }
  return date
}}
```

Hope it will help.Thank you.